# PageRequestManagerParserErrorException when attempting to send CSV data

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv

In C# I'm having trouble with printing out the csv file

As of right now it is just throwing an error, it won't print the file

The error is:

> Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed.

Here is my code behind, thanks for any help, I think I'm doing it right though

```
    protected void csvbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filename = App_Name_L.ToString();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        string[] columnNames = new string[]
        {
            "APPLICATION NAME",
            "DESCRIPTION",
            "APPLICATION OWNER",
            "TSO",
            "RESPONSIBLE MANAGER",
            "SIGN OFF",
            "CO-EXISTENCE STATUS",
            "CO-EXISTENCE PROGRESS",
            "MIGRATION PHASE",
            "NEXT STEPS",
            "LAST UPDATE"
        };
        sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", columnNames));
        sb.AppendLine(Environment.NewLine);

        string[] fields = new string[]
        {
            App_Name_L.Text.ToString(),
            Description_L.Text.ToString(),
            App_Owner_L.Text.ToString().Replace(",", "."),
            TSO_L.Text.ToString().Replace(",", "."),
            Responsible_Manager_L.Text.ToString().Replace(",", "."),
            Sign_Off_L.Text.ToString().Replace(",", "."),
            this.status_export(0, Convert.ToInt16(CS_H.Value.ToString())),
            this.status_export(1, Convert.ToInt16(CP_H.Value.ToString())),
            Migration_Phase_L.Text.ToString(),
            Next_Steps_L.Text.ToString().Replace(",", "."),
            Last_Update_L.Text.ToString()
        };
        sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", fields));

        stringout.Text = sb.ToString();

        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + filename + ".csv\"");
        Response.Write(sb.ToString());
        Response.End();
    }
```

Comment: It runs all the way through and crashes at the Response.End(); when I run it with the debugger on.

Comment: Joel can you try setting the `Response.Buffer = true;` and move the  `Response.End()` after this => `Response.Flush();` also can't you change this Response.Header line to this 
`response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName + .csv + ";");`

Comment: Set buffer to true, and added a flush

Still a no go

Comment: I will add something that I just tested with my own data that currently works I wrote a method that I am using look at how I am doing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joel this is something that I have just tested and it works in my environment look at this and see if you can apply it to your code as well replace where I have `data` with your `sb.Tostring();`

```
private static void ExportToExcel(string data)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + filename + ".csv\"");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(data);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
}
```

Comment: As I found out later, this sits in an update panel
This is the reason why I cannot get the csv to post out

Comment: That would also cause that too. Joel in the future make sure in your question that you inform someone that you are doing this within an Update Panel I am glad that my solution was able to provide you an alternative to your original solution